# How can I enable the API in AWS Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa, airflow-api

I'm testing the waters for running [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) on AWS through the [Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow](https://aws.amazon.com/managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow/) (MWAA). The version of Airflow that AWS have deployed and are managing for me is **1.10.12**.

When I try to access the v1 REST API at [`/api/experimental/test`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/rest-api-ref.html#get--api-experimental-test) I get back status code `403 Forbidden`.

Is it possible to enable the experimental API in MWAA? How?

Answer (score 5):

I think MWAA provide a REST endpoint to use the CLI

https://$WEB_SERVER_HOSTNAME/aws_mwaa/cli

It's quite confusing because you fisrt need to create a cli-token using the awscli to then hit the endpoint using that token. You will need a policy to allow your awscli to request that token.
Lastly there isn't support for all the commands, just a bunch.

Anyway it's all explained on the user guide
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/amazon-mwaa-user-guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks but I am still not able to hit the API endpoint. Could it be because I am on private webserver? @martin

Comment: You need to make the webserver public

Answer (score 3):

By default, `api.auth_backend` configuration option is set to `airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all` in MWAA environments. You need to override it to one of the authentication methods mentioned in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/security.html?highlight=auth_backend#api-authentication) as shown in the figure bellow:

[image]

Note: it is highly discouraged to use `airflow.api.auth.backend.default` as it'll
leave your environment publicly accessible.

**[2021/07/29] Edit:**
Based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884770/is-it-possible-to-access-the-airflow-api-in-aws-mwaa?noredirect=1#comment119989884_67884770), AWS blocked access to the REST API.

Comment: Thank you @hedi-bejaoui. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question. I am trying to get this done specifically in MWAA. The `AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND` is not accessible for me to set in the MWAA settings page so I am asking whether there is another way for me to open up the API in MWAA.

Comment: @urig I got your question since I was in a similar position too, probably my answer is the one who wasn't that clear. In order to override any config in the `airflow.cfg` file, you need to specify the section (the one between brackets) followed by the name of the config like this: api.auth_backend.

Comment: @urig The screenshot above is taken from the MWAA settings interface.

Comment: Is this really possible? In MWAA v2.0.2, when trying to enable this setting, I get `Some of the provided configurations belong to the blocklist and can not be applied: api.auth_backend.`. Is there another way to enable / access the Airflow API on AWS MWAA?

Comment: @ypicard Did you manage to figure out an alternative way to access Airflow api?

Comment: No, there was no way of going around the AWS restrictions at the time. I do not know if things changed since though.